# Kann "demnach" auch "der zufolge", "laut dem/der/denen" oder Ähnliches bedeuten"?

Tags: word-usage

> **demnach** - *nach dem gerade Gesagten; folglich, also*
>
> <sup>(Quelle: [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/demnach))</sup>

Ist der folgende Satz möglich?

> Die Grafik wurde am 23.04.2017 erstellt. **Demnach** sprechen sich 40% der Befragten für Neuwahlen aus.

Comment: What's about using Google before asking ... http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/demnach.php

Comment: Aus der Information, dass die Grafik am 23.04.2017 erstellt wurde, lässt sich nichts über den Inhalt der Grafik sagen. Daher finde ich nicht, dass "demnach" oder eines der oben genannten Synonyme hier passt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wie Sie bereits festgestellt haben, bezieht sich **demnach** auf das zuvor Gesagte, und zwar auf die gesamte Information des Satzes und nicht nur auf das Wort *Grafik*. Daher ist die Verwendung von **demnach** bei

> Die Grafik wurde am 23.04.2017 erstellt. **Demnach** sprechen sich 40% der Befragten für Neuwahlen aus.

widersinnig, es sei denn, die Erstellung der Grafik am 23.04.2017 wäre der Grund dafür, dass sich 40% der Befragten für Neuwahlen aussprechen. Wenn Sie sich nur auf das Wort *Grafik* beziehen möchten, können Sie **ihr zufolge**, **dieser zufolge** oder **laut dieser** verwenden:

> Die Grafik wurde am 23.04.2017 erstellt. **Ihr zufolge**/ **Dieser zufolge**/ **Laut dieser** sprechen sich 40% der Befragten für Neuwahlen aus.

Answer (score 1):

Ich denke, dass der Satz kaum missverstanden werden kann. Allerdings hätte ich geschrieben: "Aus der Grafik geht hervor, dass sich 40% der Befragten für Neuwahlen aussprechen."